# One url but different response on failure

Tags: json, swift, api

First Response on success:

```
{
    "url": "demo.web.link",
    "id": "345345dgfgdfg34534545",
    "firstName": "Apple",
    "lastName": "iOS",
    "email": "demo@web.com",
    "phone": ""
}
```

when post data is incorrect at that time getting this response:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "code": [
            "The provided code does not exist."
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using this struct:

```
struct AuthenticateResponse: Decodable {
    let url, id, firstName, lastName: String?
    let email, message, phone: String?
    let errors: Errors?
}
// MARK: - Errors
struct Errors: Decodable {
    let code: [String]?
}
```

My struct is working well for success but not working for failure. I am wondering what i am doing wrong.

Getting this error when i am providing incorrect data:

```
Error#####: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
```

success response:

```
    "RESPONSE JSON"
username Response: AuthenticateResponse(url: nil, id: nil, firstName: nil, lastName: nil, email: nil, message: nil, phone: nil, status: Optional("available"), errors: nil)
```

Comment: Where is the decoding of JSON levels: `"errors"` before getting `code`? What's the full error message when you try to decide? Did you read it?

Comment: i did. Its saying not a valid jSON but it is a valid JSON.

Comment: Please include the full error message you're getting. It's usually helpful, however the code as posted parses the JSON as expected.

Comment: How do you know it's really the JSON you receive in case of error? Is that the case, or you took it from the documentation? I did downvote previously (I removed it, since you are improving the question, but I find it's still lacking infos), because there was not enough informations. Someone with that much points on SO, could give at least the output error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as posted does correctly parse the json when passed to a `JSONDecoder` so there could be something about the context it's used in that's causing the issue.

---

However, the current model requires all the fields to be optional. This can be annoying in other parts of the app where it'll need to check for the presence of every value to show it in the UI.

It could be changed to be two separate types to remove the need for the optional fields. Then it can be wrapped as two cases in a response type they tries to decode as success, and it that fails it tries to parse as failure and returns the values.

```
enum AuthenticateResponse: Decodable {
    struct Success: Decodable {
        let url, id, firstName, lastName: String
        let email, phone: String
    }

    struct Failure: Decodable {
        struct Errors: Decodable {
            let code: [String]
        }
        
        let message: String
        let errors: Errors
    }
    
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let success = try Success(from: decoder)
            self = .success(success)
        } catch {
            let failure = try Failure(from: decoder)
            self = .failure(failure)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working :( . I have tried the same process before but not working. It's not failure. For instance authenticateCode is 23435 and this right so it will work But if  23434(wrong code) at that time it's not working. And getting this error:
Error#####: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))

Comment: when post data is incorrect at that time getting this response.  Which i mentioned as  a failure.

Comment: That error message suggests that the first character in the JSON is invalid. I'd suspect the API is returning the data in a different format than you're expecting. When you catch that error, try logging out the data from the response with `print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))`.

Comment: You are right. I am getting this
{ Status Code: 404, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, private"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 17 Jan 2022 23:55:07 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Linux
    );
    “demo-request-id" =     (
        34543dfdgdg
    );
    "x-powered-by" =     (
        "PHP/7.4.9"
    );
} })

Comment: Getting a HTML body

Comment: That's the response, not the returned data, right? What's the returned data?

Answer (score 0):

It's working when you insert incorrect data at that point need to set your header by force to

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Before i was using :

```
if path.httpMethod == .get {
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
}
```